# Как в C++ реализовать ассиацию из типов под SFINAE?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, sfinae

Как в C++ реализовать категорию типов с примерами SFINAE ([std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), [std::is_integral](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral))?
Например, требуется чтобы структура при вызове get_type::type = integer имела ассоциацию из типов перечислений.

Вот код

```
enum type_t {
   integer,
   other
};

//Default
template <typename T>
struct get_type {
    static constexpr type_t type = other;
};
// For integer 
template <>
struct get_type<int> {
    static constexpr type_t type = integer;
};
```

Мне например не хочется заполнять для каждого примитивного типа int, unsigned int, long (etc.) и попробую использовать [std::is_integral](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral), как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если не усложнять, то годится?

```
template<typename T>
struct get_type
{
    static constexpr type_t type = is_integral_v<T> ? integer : other;
};
```

См. https://ideone.com/S2Ix3b - там, правда, в связи с более старой версией использован `is_integral<T>::value`.

Comment: приведенный пример достаточно очевиден, а как быть для других типов?
UPD: пополню перечисления. 
```enum type_t {
   integer,
   float, 
   bool,
   other
};```

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Это работает для любых типов.

Comment: пополню перечисления. enum type_t {    integer,    float,     bool,    other };

Comment: Для этого нужно использовать соответствующие свойства типов...  См. https://ideone.com/26GB5C - только надо самые конкретные вперед выносить, чтоб более общие не перебивали...

Comment: при использование спецификатора constexpr, данный вопрос закрыт. А что если я использую более прошедшую версию языка?

Comment: Какую? С++03? Так там еще и `is_integral` нет, его надо свой писать :) Тогда уж специализируйте для каждого типа. Хотя стоп! Как это нет? Вы же его написали сами, в вопросе!! Ну в конце концов, напишите `static const type_t type = is_integral_v<T> ? integer : other;` — вот вам и нет `constexpr`. Так годится?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141800/discussion-between-badcast-and-harry).